# CloudPages and SmartCapture

Tags: marketing-cloud

I created a SmartCapture (not in "classic" as I was told not to do so) and am having trouble activating the button. The whole point of creating a SmartCapture is to add a form onto a Marketing Cloud landing page. I enter my email address and the button won't click. Which means it's a dead page. Any ideas of how to go about getting the button to submit the form? Is my data extension bad? I checked off "use for sending"

Kind of lost here...

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem with SmarCapture and cloud page. The button to submit doesn't work at all. I have raised a support case on this and they said it works on their environment. So I have tried using a different DE and to my surprise, it works.

So I have created a brand new DE with exactly same attributes and I used that DE in the smart capture and it worked.

Yes there is something wrong with the current DE, support suggested that we import a file into the DE and see if it works. I haven't tried yet but will let you know soon.

I think for now you can try with a new DE.